# C# Reference parameter passing

Tags: c#, parameters, ref

i have a piece of code that isn't working, i'd appreciate any help you guys can provide me

the code below is generating an exception ... but i'd think it shouldn't, unless i'm misinterpreting the ref semantics.

EDIT: thanks for all the answer ... i know i'm instatiating a new Queue object in the One.Produce method ... but this is what i actually want to do, i would like for Main._queue to hold a reference to One._queue.
Is that possible at all ?

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace ConsoleApplication2
{
    class One
    {
        Queue<string> _queue;

        public One(ref Queue<string> queue)
        {
            // should be assigning by reference
            _queue = queue;
        }

        public void Produce()
        {
            _queue = new Queue<string>();
            _queue.Enqueue("one");
        }
    }

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            Queue<string> _queue = new Queue<string>();

            One one = new One(ref _queue);
            one.Produce();

            // this generates an exception, since _queue is empty
            // i'd have thought _queue would have one item, "one"
            string value = _queue.Dequeue();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: The exception it generates would be very helpful ...

Comment: To respond to your edit, you are saying that you want to instantiate a new instance of `Queue<string>` in `One.Produce` but you want the local `_queue` in `Main` to refer to that object too. In that case you either need to change the signature of `Produce` to be `Produce(ref Queue<string> queue)` and add the line `queue = _queue = new Queue<string>()` or you need to have `Produce` return a reference to the instance of `Queue<string>` that it creates and set `_queue = one.Produce()` in `Main`.

Comment: Returning a reference would be the easiest, or change ref to out.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is that in the function `Produce` you are instantiating a new `Queue` and assigning this to the private member `One._queue`; this overwrites that assignment that you made to `One._queue` in the constructor. However, the local `_queue` refers to a different `Queue<string>` on which you never enqueued.

You can fix this by removing your first line of `Produce` to obtain the following:

```
public void Produce() {
        _queue.Enqueue("one");
}
```

By the way, you don't need to pass `_queue` by reference into the constructor to achieve what you are trying to achieve. That is, the following will work too

```
public One(Queue<string> queue) {
    _queue = queue;
}
```

Passing by reference would be used when you want the local `_queue` in main to refer to a different instance of `Queue<string>` after the `One` constructor executes.

Comment: thanks .. the thing is that i want Main._queue to be updated ... i know that i'm instatiating a new Queue object, but that's exactly what i want to do ... i'll edit the main post to better reflect this

Comment: If you pass `_queue` into the constructor of `One` and assign it to `One._queue` then the local `_queue` in main and `One._queue` will refer to the same object. Passing by reference is not needed to achieve this. The problem that you encountered is that you then set `One._queue` to refer to a different object with the assignment `_queue = new Queue<string>();` whereas the local `_queue` in `Main` still referred to the initial instance of `Queue<string>`.

Comment: jason, pls check my answer below ... too long for comments

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
    public One(Queue<string> queue)
    {
        // should be assigning by reference
        _queue = queue;
    }

    public void Produce()
    {
        _queue.Enqueue("one");
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Inside your `Produce()` method, remove this line:

```
_queue = new Queue<string>();
```

There you're creating a new queue instance.

Answer (score 0):

one.Produce() replaces the _queue with a new "empty" Queue().
That's why string value = _queue.Dequeue() is throwing an error (b/c the _queue)

Answer (score 0):

Remove this line from your `Produce` method:

```
_queue = new Queue<string>();
```

This is wiping out the reference to the existing `Queue<String>` that you passing in by reference with a new reference to a new `Queue<String>`.

Answer (score 0):

### The Problem

The problem is that the `ref` keyword will only affect the method it was declared. So, you would be able to change `Main`'s queue in `One`'s constructor, but not in the `Produce` method.

In your code, `One` is creating a second reference to the same queue object. The `Produce` method is simply changing this second reference.

In other words, when you make a call to a method passing a parameter by reference, the called method will be able to change the referenced object, but only at this call site. After the call returns, whatever object is referenced by the `_queue` variable at the `Main` method will remain there.

One other consideration. The assignment at `One`'s constructor (where you commented "*should be assigning by reference*") works in exactly the same way as it would work if the `ref` keyword wasn't there. Only if the assignment was inverted to `queue = _queue;` then the `ref` keyword would make a difference.

---

### Solution A - `Holder<T>` class

One solution that might make sense would be to create a `Holder` class like this:

```
public class Holder<T> {
    public T { get; set; }
}
```

Then, the `One` class would work on a `Holder<Queue<string>>` object. The `Main` method would have to work on `Holder<Queue<string>>` too. This way, `One` could change the queue instance and it would be reflected in `Main`.

Ok, ok. I know this solution is very awkward, but the requirements for your question seems awkward to me too. Is it a rhetorical question? Or are you trying to solve a bigger problem here? If it's the latter, I'm curious to know what is this bigger problem.

---

### Solution B - pointers

Another solution would be to use [pointers](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2yzs44b.aspx). It's perfectly possible to be done in C#, but not at all recommended. If you are interested, I can try to write a solution using pointers.

---

### Solution C - Single position array

Your own answer gave me the idea for a third possible solution. It's intrinsically very similar to the other two solutions. Instead of explaining it in English, let me show it in C#.

```
class One
{
    Queue<string>[] queueArray;

    public One(Queue<string>[] queueArray)
    {
        if (queueArray == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("queueArray");
        if (queueArray.Length != 1) throw new ArgumentException("queueArray must have one and only one item");
        this.queueArray = queueArray;
    }

    public void Produce()
    {
        queueArray[0] = new Queue<string>();
        queueArray[0].Enqueue("one");
    }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var queueArray = new Queue<string>[] { new Queue<string>() };

        One one = new One(queueArray);
        one.Produce();

        string value = queueArray[0].Dequeue(); //this line sets "one" to value
    }
}
```

Comment: jpbochi, yes i'm working on a bigger problem .. pls check answer below ... too long for comments

Comment: I read your answer carefully and it gave me the idea for a 3rd solution. Plz, check it out.

Comment: I wrote some more consideration at the start of the answer too. BTW, is it possible to you to provide us a bigger picture of the problem you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you simply do the following:

```
public void Produce()
{
    _queue.Clear();
    _queue.Enqueue("one");
}
```

Comment: the .Clear() function for the Queue has the effect of basically creating a new Queue without creating a new reference.  This way you still keep the same reference in both Main and One and it becomes empty.

Answer (score -1):

General approach for this kind of problem....step through the code with the debugger and see what line causes the exception to be thrown.